# Custom tkinter label background

Tags: python, tkinter, customtkinter

I am making a school project, and right now I'm having a problem with the label's backgrounds.

[image]

[image]

the objective is to make the label's background the same as the frame in both dark and light themes, and if possible, remove the little different color on the edges of the buttons.

[image]

[image]

```
import tkinter
import customtkinter
root_tk = customtkinter.CTk()  # create CTk window like you do with the Tk window
root_tk.geometry("1280x720")
root_tk.minsize(1280, 720)
class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root_tk):
        Frame1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk)
        Frame1.pack
        frame2 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(Frame1, width=100, height=720)
        frame2.pack(pady=20,padx=20)
        frame3 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk, width=250, height=725)
        frame3.pack()
        frame3.place(anchor="w", relx=0.0, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.2, relheight=1)
        self.test()

    def test(self):
        self.switch = customtkinter.CTkSwitch(master=root_tk, text="Dark Mode", command=self.theme_change)
        self.switch.toggle(1)
        self.switch.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.05)
        self.label_width = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root_tk, text="glasses width:")
        self.label_width.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.67, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
        self.label_height = customtkinter.CTkLabel(root_tk, text="glasses height:")
        self.label_height.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.77, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
        self.button_add_Face = customtkinter.CTkButton(root_tk, width=200, height=50, border_width=0, corner_radius=8, hover=True, text="Adicionar Rostos", command=print("added"))
        self.button_add_Face.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.6, anchor=tkinter.CENTER)
    def theme_change(self):
        if self.switch.get() == 1:
            customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        else:
            customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("light")   
start = GUI(root_tk)
root_tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you using this [CostumTkinter](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter) modul? Because it isnt tagged.

Comment: i couldn't find that tag, but yes I'm using customtkinter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code of the [`CTkBaseClass`](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/9d618386e1d3f0c00a9006f70f7363ca6d979245/customtkinter/widgets/widget_base_class.py#L19) for the widgets. The background color should be the same as the `fg_color` of your master as long as you haven't defined explicitly a `bg_color` for your widget.

Look at the [configure](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/9d618386e1d3f0c00a9006f70f7363ca6d979245/customtkinter/widgets/widget_base_class.py#L112) method of the `BaseClass` and follow it to the [detect_color_of_master](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/9d618386e1d3f0c00a9006f70f7363ca6d979245/customtkinter/widgets/widget_base_class.py#L138).

> the objective is to make the label's background the same as the frame
> in both dark and light themes

So this should do the trick:

```
Frame1 = customtkinter.CTkFrame(root_tk,fg_color=root_tk.fg_color)
Frame1.pack()

self.button_add_Face = customtkinter.CTkButton(Frame1, width=200, height=50, border_width=0, corner_radius=8, hover=True, text="Adicionar Rostos", command=print("added"), border_color=root_tk.fg_color)
```

But you may are more interested in the [ThemeManager](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/blob/master/customtkinter/theme_manager.py). There are some [Themes](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/tree/master/customtkinter/assets/themes) and you could just do another `.json` file in the form of the examples and add it in this directory to apply your own style.

Comment: @Lucifer_uwu take a look in the [dokumentation](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki) and the section [themes](https://github.com/TomSchimansky/CustomTkinter/wiki/Themes). They made it really easy.